# Avoid pagebreak between equation and label

Tags: equations, line-breaking, page-breaking, labels

I have a very long equation which barely fits into one line, but the label does not and is positioned one line below. The problem is that if the equation is at the end of a page, the label is moved to the next page.

If possible, I would like to keep the equation as is (no splitting up into two lines, no decreasing the font size), but label should always be directly below the equation.

**Edit to provide further information:**

Trying to construct a MWE, I think I found the cause, but still no way around. The problem occurs when using the Springer `svjour3` class (http://www.springeropen.com/authors/tex) in conjunction with the `amsmath` package. Not loading `amsmath` puts the label into the same line.

Unfortunately, this seems not to be an option as I need for example `\DeclareMathOperator`, besides `amsmath` is loaded by `tikz` anyways.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here}
\author{First Author}
\maketitle

\section{Section title}
\label{sec:1}
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
\vspace{12cm}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2=c^2.
\end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you mind showing some code that gives rise to the unsatisfactory situation?

Comment: by default a label won't split like that, how have you marked this up?

Comment: maybe you have blank line befor your equation (new paragraph). You should remove it as paragraphs don't start with equation normaly.

Comment: Check out the AMS packages for math. The plain LaTeX ones aren't precisely stellar.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I can reproduce the problem with article.cls, `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}` and suitable vspace before the equation. The label is in the second column.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes but that's cheating (generating a MWE from inside knowledge:-) the amsmath fleqn implementation isn't a display math environment at all (really) as you know. But anyway an MWE has appeared, I see.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have no inside knowledge about amsmath implementation of fleqn ;-). I only saw in the svjour3.cls that is passes fleqn to amsmath and guessed it could matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cramp up the horizontal spacing (to rather dangerously small values) then it fits:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here}
\author{First Author}
\maketitle

\section{Section title}
\label{sec:1}
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
\vspace{12cm}

\begin{equation}
\medmuskip=0mu
\thickmuskip=1mu
a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2=c^2.
\end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively if you want the same layout, but in an unbreakable unit, you can use a minipage

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2=c^2.
\end{equation} 
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. This would definitely avoid the equation and the label being split up. If possible, I am looking for a solution where the original equation stays untouched and the label is in the next line below (just not on another page).

Comment: @jpmath `\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{equation}...` ?

Comment: That does it! If you like to edit this into your answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @jpmath updated